# Java Optional Usage: still demande try-catch block by Eclipse

Tags: java-8, option-type

I'm trying to use Optional of Java 8 and I meet some problemes.

I think by using Optional, there is no more need to do existence check.(please correct me if i'm wrong). So i do the following:

```
public Optional<File> ipModeFile(String ipMode) {
        File file = new File(ipMode);
        if(file.exists()) {
            return Optional.of(file);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

then I use it like this:

```
if(ipV4ModeFile.isPresent()) {
    File file = ipV4ModeFile.get();
    FileWriter writer;
    writer = new FileWriter(file, false); // Unhandled exception type IOException
    writer.write(TURNOFF_IPV4); 
    writer.close(); 
}
```

One of the advantages of Optional isn't just the possibility to omit some null check?

Comment: You want `Optional.ifPresent(lambda)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `FileWriter` isn't [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Even if it were, the [Option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) (aka a maybe type) protects againsts `NullPointerException` (not `IOException`). From the `Optional` Javadoc,

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value.

Comment: I see the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It’s worth noting, that a `file.exists()` may make a `FileNotFoundException` unlikely but not impossible. It’s a check-then-act pattern which is not thread-safe (nor immune to in-between changes made by other processes). Therefore Java will always insist on handling `FileNotFoundException`, regardless of whether `file.exists()` has been verified right before the operation.